# No output in basic C program

Tags: c, output

I have been reading the first chapter of K&R, but I am having trouble with one of the very first problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count digits, white space, others */

main(){

        int c, i, nwhite, nother;
        int ndigit[10];

        nwhite = nother = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                ndigit[i] = 0;

        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
                if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
                else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                        ++nwhite;
                else
                        ++nother;
        printf("digits =");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
        printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
                nwhite, nother);

}
```

I have zero output in the terminal from this. I have tried many different variations of this, but can not seem to get it to output and numbers.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: First mistake K&R is very old, don't read it for learning. Read it to learn the history of the language only. You have a very K&Rish mistake, `main()` must return `int`.

Comment: do `./a.out <  test.txt`

Comment: Can you run a "hello world" program?

Comment: Your program works fine for me. Are you pressing `Ctrl-C` instead of `Ctrl-D` when passing input from your shell?

Comment: It just works fine. Type something and press `ctrl+D`. The meaning for the `(c = getchar()) != EOF` is it reads the characters you type and waits until you press `ctrl+D` and prints the character stats.

Comment: Why not use braces for every for.while loop and also for if statements. Makes the code readable and also prevents mistakes

Comment: @iharob K&R is mostly OK for learning except for the implicit int issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program requires an input file to be passed to it, but it works as is.

```
 gcc test.c -o test
 echo "12345" > data
 ./test < data

 digits = 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0, white space = 1, other = 0
```

Here is another output:

```
 echo "111 111 222" > data
 ./test < data

 digits = 0 6 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, white space = 3, other = 0
```

Comment: I copy pasted the OP's code into test.c then compiled and ran it.

Comment: Sorry, I read *requires an input file* and didn't see the `./test < data`. Would you mention the incorrect `main()` signature please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you do not normally input `EOF` from the console. As stated in [Tony Ruths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568610/1548311), it works by redirecting a file to `stdin` of the program, because files are terminated by `EOF`. Since the entire file is then passed into `stdin`, which is read by the program via `getch()`, the "end of the input" gets recognized the correct way.

You just don't get to input `EOF` via the console, thus not getting any output. (actually there might be some special shortcut for `EOF`)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, in the years since K&R came out, we have learned a lot about what makes code more reliable/maintainable.   Some examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count digits, white space, others */

int main ( void ) {                 /* type explicitly */

        int c;                      /* declare 1 variable per line */
        int i;
        int nwhite     = 0;         /* initialize variables when possible */
        int nother     = 0;
        int ndigit[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {          /* use brackets */
                if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {   /* explicit precedence is clearer */
                        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
                } else if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\n') || (c == '\t')) {
                        ++nwhite;
                } else {
                        ++nother;
                }
        }
        printf("digits =");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) printf(" %d", ndigit[i]); /* 1 liner is ok w/{} */
        printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
        return 0;                            /* don't forget a return value */
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the examples. I was always told that K&R was a great way to learn C. By everyone's comments I'm starting to see that it's prehistoric for today's standards. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @woodfordb I think you've got yourself into a very unfortunate situation because of asking the question and you've started feeling this way now. IMHO you should definitely proceed with K&R and finish it. I never needed much of any outside material for learning C other than K&R.

Comment: @scarecrow I'm definitely going to continue with K&R. It still seems like it's one of the best ways to learn the C language. I'll just be looking more carefully at the problems in the book. Thanks for the insight.